# Asp.net project breaks when checking out on a different machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I'm trying to use TFS with the git plugin as version control, but anytime I check out it out on a different machine, or even in a different directory on the original machine, I get the following errors and warnings.  I turned on NuGet Package Restore and I have added the package directory to the repository, but it still breaks.  What am I doing wrong?  This is an ASP.NET MVC 4 project being developed with VS Express 2012 for Web.

```
    Warning 13  Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Antlr3.Runtime". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.   TimeSheets
    Warning 5   Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. TimeSheets
    Warning 6   Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "DotNetOpenAuth.Core, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.   TimeSheets
    Warning 8   Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.  TimeSheets
    Warning 7   Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Consumer, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. TimeSheets
    Warning 9   Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. TimeSheets
    Warning 10  Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.    TimeSheets
    Warning 1   Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "EntityFramework". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.  TimeSheets
    Warning 2   Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Microsoft.Web.Mvc.FixedDisplayModes, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.   TimeSheets
    Warning 3   Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Newtonsoft.Json". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.  TimeSheets
    Warning 11  Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "System.Web.Http.OData, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. TimeSheets
    Warning 4   Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "System.Web.Optimization". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.  TimeSheets
    Warning 12  Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "WebGrease". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.    TimeSheets
    Warning 64  The referenced component 'Antlr3.Runtime' could not be found.   TimeSheets
    Warning 56  The referenced component 'DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet' could not be found.    TimeSheets
    Warning 57  The referenced component 'DotNetOpenAuth.Core' could not be found.  TimeSheets
    Warning 59  The referenced component 'DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth' could not be found.     TimeSheets
    Warning 58  The referenced component 'DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Consumer' could not be found.    TimeSheets
    Warning 60  The referenced component 'DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId' could not be found.    TimeSheets
    Warning 61  The referenced component 'DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty' could not be found.   TimeSheets
    Warning 52  The referenced component 'EntityFramework' could not be found.  TimeSheets
    Warning 53  The referenced component 'Microsoft.Web.Mvc.FixedDisplayModes' could not be found.  TimeSheets
    Warning 54  The referenced component 'Newtonsoft.Json' could not be found.  TimeSheets
    Warning 62  The referenced component 'System.Web.Http.OData' could not be found.    TimeSheets
    Warning 55  The referenced component 'System.Web.Optimization' could not be found.  TimeSheets
    Warning 63  The referenced component 'WebGrease' could not be found.    TimeSheets
```

Comment: looks clear to me, could not resolve reference.

Comment: Sounds like you are not including the `packages.config`. Can you verify that it is included in the project? Check the root of your web project.

Comment: Looks clear to me also. Make sure those references are relative and not hardcoded.

Comment: packages.config is included in the repository. I'm pretty new to .net, so how do I go about checking all the references are relative? All the controllers, views, etc were scaffolded in VS.

Comment: I havent used Nuget, so cant comment on that part but to just check the relative reference path, you can open up the project file and search for the <HintPath> tag, make sure they are relative and not hardcoded.

Comment: I ended up redoing my git repository and excluding the packages and bin folders. This seemed to do the trick. Thanks for your time.

Comment: What you're doing wrong is right in the body of your question: You're using MVC4. ASP.NET MVC4 isn't suitable for release yet. It's alpha quality software.

Comment: @EdPlunkett, MVC 4 was released in 2012, but the question was asked in 2013 and your comment is in 2015.